# Sleep and output flush

Tags: c

I saw the snippet below somewhere online. The following program doesnt print "hello-out". The reason I feel is because before it is actually flushed to the console from the buffer,

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <unistd.h>
  int main()
  {
          while(1)
          {
                  fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
                  fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
                  sleep(1);
          }
          return 0;
  }
```

Is my reason correct? If not what is the correct reason?

Comment: It could be because `stdout` is being redirected to a file or elsewhere while `stderr` is going to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `\n` at the end of the string to have it flushed, or use `fflush` to force it out.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the following **fix** is because I do know that stdout is line-buffered by default, whereas stderr is not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        fprintf(stdout,"hello-out");
        fflush(stdout);
        // sleep(1);
        fprintf(stderr,"hello-err");
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Update** another way to 'fix' it without changing the source code is by using e.g. [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/s/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html):

```
 stdbuf -o 0 ./test
```

which switches standard output to unbuffer mode as well. Interestingly, if you specify

```
 stdbuf -e L ./test
```

to make stderr linebuffered as well, no output will appear at all (until the first lineend gets printed)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the `stdbuf` command, though it seems to be a non-standard glibc extension.